# How to fix my mysql request with group by or not?

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have a problem with my MySQL request.

I have this extract of my table :

```
colA  | colB
64783 | 50000000000000
64783 | 50000000000000
65443 | 53757101000025
65443 | 53757101000041
```

This is my rule :

if I have always the same colB for my value in colA, then I put :

```
64783 | 50000000000000
```

if not my rule, then I do nothing.

I try and I try but I don't have a good MySQL request to do this.

I would like to do this with only one MySQL request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are just looking for `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct colA, colB from mytable
```

This generates a unique record in the result for each distinct `(colA, colB)` title.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d12452103fb1c87cfc2af109810f2c3)** with your sample data returns:

```
 colA |           colB
----: | -------------:
64783 | 50000000000000
65443 | 53757101000025
65443 | 53757101000041
```

---

If you are looking for the tuples that occur more than once, then you can use aggregation and a `HAVING` clause for filtering:

```
select colA, colB
from mytable
group by colA, colB
having count(*) > 1
```

For your sample data, this will return only one record:

```
 colA |           colB
----: | -------------:
64783 | 50000000000000
```